# Salesforce CLI not working with Visual Studio Code on MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-cli

I am not sure where the issue is. I am trying to get the Salesforce CLI and VS Code development flow set up so I can start working, but I am running into basic issues that don't seem to be experienced in the Salesforce provided training and videos. I am on a 2021 Macbook Pro.

I am following the basic [Trailhead tutorial to set up a [Salesforce DX Environment](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-salesforce-dx) and have followed every step below

1. Install Salesforce CLI
2. Run 'sfdx' to ensure it works
   [image]
3. (re)installed Visual Studio Code
4. Install the Salesforce Extension Pack (current version v51.13.0)
5. Run Command+Shift+P and type 'sfdx' in the command pallet to confirm that the extension has been installed
   [image]
6. Successfully run Command+Shift+P and type 'sfdx:: create project'
7. FAILED to run Command+Shift+P and type 'sfdx: authorize an org' -> Project Default -> enter
   [image]

When I do step 7, I get an error that shows it is attempting to use the Integrate CLI to run the auth command but is followed by 'Salesforce CLI is not installed' [image]

When I run the command directly

> sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias lwttest --instanceurl
> https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
> I get the expected flow of a browser opening and having to authorize access.
> [image]

I have been trying to find a solution for 2 days and have had no luck, a lot of issues on the web seem to be for Windows but I am having this issue on a Mac.

- This is on a company computer
- I am not on a Corporate firewall, I am using my at home internet
- I have tested this on a different (personal) Mac and was able to follow the Trailhead without issue

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Try install the CLI from the salesforce developer site

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli